# Instantiate custom view programmatically the right way

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view called `EventItemView` which I'm using in **both** an XML file and in a custom adapter (which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter` and is used in a `RecyclerView`). My problem is that its appearance in my `RecyclerView` is weird but not in my XML file :

[image]

1. Declared using XML
2. Instantiated dynamically in my adapter

And I believe this is due to the way I instanciate views in my adapter, by doing `new EventItemView(context)` and not passing it additional arguments `AttributeSet, int, int` that are probably needed for it to render like the XML version. The problem is that I don't know how to get them in my adapter.

Here's custom view declaration :

**EventItemView.java**

```
public class EventItemView extends FrameLayout {
    public EventItemView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public EventItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public EventItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public EventItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    protected void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        eventItem = new EventItem();

        inflate(context, R.layout.view_event_item, this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        TypedArray values = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EventItemView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        try {
            setSubtitle(values.getString(R.styleable.EventItemView_subtitle));
            ...
        }
        finally {
            values.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

**layout/view_event_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_item_event"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

This view is then used in 1) an **activity.xml** file :

```
<com.app.package.view.EventItemView
    android:id="@+id/current_event_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

and 2) in **Adapter.java** :

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    EventItemView itemView = new EventItemView(context);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

How can I properly instantiate my custom view with the relevant `attrs`, `defStyleAttr` and `defStyleRes` constructor parameters? Or maybe the view is behaving in a weird way for a totally different reason?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved my problem by changing

```
public class EventItemView extends FrameLayout
```

to

```
public class EventItemView extends RelativeLayout
```

I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `measure()` and then `layout()`.

An instantiated custom view doesn't know the sizes its need to inflate to, so you need to pass it with those calls.

Comment: If in my adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` I use `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_event, parent, false)` to get a `View` object, the view get correctly laid out and displayed yet I'm not passing any size either.

Comment: `inflate()` does that for you.